# How to structure a cron job and script to execute sql command

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

I have a MySQL database accessible through CPANEL.  I want to execute a SQL command to DELETE from dbtable where `eventdate` = 'YYYY-MM-DD'. This is my cron job.

```
curl -L --max-redirs 1000 -v "https://ottawaoc.ca/test/files/delete_dates.sh" 1>/dev/null
```

and here is the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql --user = "ottawaoc_test" --password = "test ps" --database = "ottawaoc_test" --execute ="DELETE FROM `h8be5_eventregistration` WHERE `eventdate` = '2020-09-27'"
```

(I do insert the correct password.)
I get output mailed to me and it seems to get the shell script but nothing happens within the database.

Could someone help to give me the correct commands and/or tell me how I can get errors from MySQL.

Comment: That's not how CGI works. Your CGI code needs to return proper headers.

Answer (score 1):

I used to run mysql crons by putting this in the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "mysql statement;" | mysql -B -hHOST -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME
```